# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt{n}}}$ $\\$

I tried a comparison test, Leibniz, Cauchy, Cauchy-integral and D'Alembert criteria but nothing gives me the result. Any hints would be helpful!

Comment: First, find an asymptotic for $1+\sqrt2+\cdots+\sqrt n$.

Comment: Do you need to find the value or to determine whether the sum converges?

Comment: I think he wants to know whether the sum converges, but I'd really like to see if there is an explicit value!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What do you mean? I can't see where you're heading.

Comment: @iskra Find a simple expression such that $f(n)\sim 1+\sqrt2+\cdots+\sqrt n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt{k}}$,but I really don't see how that helps me, sorry

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci - probably just under $3.167830$

Comment: @iskra Look below.

Comment: @Henry yeah, but it'd be beautiful to see if there is a closed form for that result. In fact we have that that sum is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{H_{n,\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci It does not seem to appear in Plouffe's Inverter,  though $\frac{63}{20} + \frac{7}{680}\sqrt{3}$ is not far away

Comment: I'll do a question for this!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335773/explicit-value-for-sum-n-1-infty-left-frac1-sqrt1-sqrt2-dots

Comment: @iskra why you don't find any help from Lord Shark's comment is not understandable. $1+\sqrt{2}+\dots +\sqrt{n}\thicksim cn^{3/2}$, $c>0$ do not depend on $n$. He is talking about $f(n)$ like $cn^{3/2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much @MANMAID! I understand now what I've been doing wrong.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you, I see what was your intention. This is the simplest method as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**hint**

For $k=1,2,...n $,

$$\int_{k-1}^k\sqrt {t}dt <\sqrt {k}<\int_k^{k+1}\sqrt {t}dt $$

by sum,

$$\int_0^n\sqrt {t}dt <\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt {k}. $$

Answer (score 5):

Use AM-GM inequality and we get $\frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\dots +\sqrt{n}}{n}>\sqrt[n]{(n!)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ and then use the result $(n!)^2>n^n$, when $n=3,4,\dots$(Why?).

Note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$ is finite if $s>1$

Comment: lol! why I got downvoted?

Comment: Minor quibble:  the (strict) inequality $(n!)^2\gt n^n$ does not hold for $n=1$ or $2$.  Otherwise very nice.  (I saw the question a couple of hours ago and thought about using AM-GM, but I couldn't see an easy way to turn the factorial into an $n$th power.)

Comment: @BarryCipra you are right, I should have mentioned it! But it is very known result, I thought that would not necessary

Comment: If you change $\gt$ to $\ge$, then my minor quibble goes away.

Comment: @BarryCipra more useful suggestion would be the edit I did now!! Since we are showing convergence, this minor edit will not effect much though, you may see my comment in this post, and may help to find better value https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335773/explicit-value-for-sum-n-1-infty-left-frac1-sqrt1-sqrt2-dots

Answer (score 3):

Compare it with harmonic series. As $\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k} = \Omega(n^{1.5})$, you can conclude that this series is convergent. And for the claim you can prove it by the following:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k} \geq  \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}} + \cdots+\sqrt{n}\geq \frac{n}{2}\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$$