# Explicit value for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\dots+\sqrt{n}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This question came out from this [other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335680/convergence-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt):

Is there an explicit value for this series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\dots+\sqrt{n}}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{i}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{H_{n,-\frac{1}{2}}}$$

As someone pointed out in comments to the other question, this value is a little bit lower than $3.167830$ and it's not far away from $\frac{63}{20}+\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{680}$.

Can we go further on this? Can we reach an exact value or a better approximation?

Comment: shouldn't be $1/H_{n,-1/2}$ ?

Comment: I found $\zeta (1.5)-1/2^{1.5}+1/(1+\sqrt{2})$ is a crude upper bound, see here my solution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335680/convergence-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt/2335702?noredirect=1#comment4808914_2335702

Comment: Sure, edited. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, nice upper bound. But we should work finding something better!

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci (if you are telling me), you are right! that's why I wrote "crude"

Comment: Sure I know! But nice work!

Comment: By creative telescoping we have
$$ \frac{1}{H_{n,-1/2}} \approx \frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{3}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{9}{8}\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
where the shown approximation is correct up to the term $n^{-7/2}$ in the asymptotic expansion.  The complete asymptotic expansion of $H_{n,-1/2}^{-1}$ is not that nice...

Answer (score 4):

Just computing, the best value I obtained is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{H_{n,-\frac{1}{2}}}=3.16782938772351480$$ which can be rationalized as $$\frac{5908}{1865}\qquad \frac{7720}{2437}\qquad \frac{15893}{5017}\qquad\frac{87638}{27665}\qquad \frac{247021}{77978}\qquad\frac{828701}{261599}\qquad\frac{3067783}{968418}\qquad \frac{6964267}{2198435}$$ with increasing accuracy. The decimal representation of the last one is $3.16782938772353970$.

Inverse symbolic calculators did not find anything very close to this number.