# How to find this summation?

Tags: calculus

Find the summation of

> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+…+\sqrt{n}}$

I only know that $a_{n+1} = (1-\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+…+\sqrt{n+1}})a_n$ and $a_1 = 1$
and this $a_n$ approaches infinity as n approaches infinity.

Comment: Surely $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: The sum converges, however, it's not likely that any closed form expression exists.

Comment: This is not a joke : claim that it is close to $\pi$ (which is true)

Comment: Not _that_ close. It's about $3.17$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2335773/42969

Comment: To see that the sum is convergent one can note, for example, that for each $n$ the sum $\sqrt{1} + \dots + \sqrt{n}$ is a sum of $n$ strictly increasing terms, the last $n/2$ of which (or approximately $n/2$ of which, if $n$ is odd) are at least $\sqrt{n/2}$.  So for each $n$ the sum $\sqrt{1} + \dots + \sqrt{n}$ is larger than about $(n/2)^{3/2}$, and your series is thus comparable to a multiple of a convergent "$p$-series," e.g. with $p = 3/2$.